# Using a server to preform tasks from html page

Tags: html, perl

I'm not an experienced programmer and therefor I'll try to describe what I'm trying to do and hopefully you can instruct me whether or not it's possible and if so maybe help me or direct me to some sort of documentation. BTW I'm using a linux environment.

I'm trying set up a form inside a HTML page that when I fill the form and press some kind of a button, a local server will preform a calculation and will launch gnuplot, based on the information filled in the form.
Since I have more experience with perl I think I have more chances of succeeding if the server is going to be written in perl. Is it possible?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sobrique suggesting CGI.pm in this day and age is not wise, it's outdated. [CGI has been removed from the perl core](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI.pm-4.03/lib/CGI.pm#CGI.pm_HAS_BEEN_REMOVED_FROM_THE_PERL_CORE) discusses the issue in detail, [CGI::Alternatives](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI-Alternatives-0.11/lib/CGI/Alternatives.pm) lists suggested alternatives

Comment: Fair enough. Comment deleted.

Comment: Yes, this is possible using Perl, however your question doesn't lend itself to a SO style answer (use code `xyz...`). You want to use a modern Perl framework such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) (see my previous comment for a list of alternatives). It sounds like you also want to use AJAX to interact with the Perl back end. This is fairly standard these days. There are several perl interfacesto GNU plot on cpan.